# Ido - how autocomplete everything?

Tags: ido, smex

Emacs 26.1
I use ido mode with same.

It is work nice.
But I need ido interactively autocomplete for :

- bookmarks
- shell history commands

Is it possible?

Comment: Have you tried using `ido-ubiquitous` from the `ido-completing-read+` package?

Comment: It's autocomplete bookmarks. Nice. But what about "input history" (comint-dynamic-list-input-ring) in shell mode?